# How to move text next to an image without the text keep changing its position on zooming in and out CSS

Tags: html, css

[Explanatory pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhALG.jpg)I have this text that is a block level element
under it a bunch of pictures organized in the way you can see.
problem happens when I try to absolute position it down on the text it goes where i want but then zooming in and out the text change its position goes up.
is the a way to stably position a text on an image (div) ? without this up/down movement of the text
the pictures dont move at all every this is stable but only this text.

```css
.Lower {
    max-width: 450px;
    margin-top: 50px;

}
```

```html
     <div>
       <div>
                <P class="Lower">
                about lorem 150
                </P>
            </div>
            <div><img id="A1" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img id="A2" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A2.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img id="A3" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A3.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img id="A4" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A4.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img id="A5" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A5.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img id="A6" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A6.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img id="A7" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A7.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img id="A8" src="./imgs/About/Aboutria/A8.jpg" alt=""></div>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a structure like this

```
<div>
    <div class="caption">Here is a picture of a bird</div>
    <img src="...."/>
</div>
```

css using `position: absolute` will be invariant to zooming if the `div` it is in is invariant to zooming (as you describe that you have with the pictures).  `absolute` places it relative to it's nearest ancestor, i.e. your top level `div`.

```
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: still the text is hopping up and down and it is not fixed in its position it seems once I move the text down by using top/down to the the other div with pictures , this problem starts to appear.

Comment: Here is a working example of what I did
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-sun-6c504
Pay attention to the fact the class to move the text has to be on the same level as the images.